# How to add the TextView to the layout programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make messages like in `messenger`. They must appear one after another. So I use the `LinearLayout` and add the `TextView` to it. But the appear all at once. I use the loop, but it looks like it doesn't work!
Here is the code

```
final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.line_layout);
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 500, 50);
        int i = 0;
        for (final Task task : tasks) {
            i = i + 1;

            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {

                final TextView message = new TextView(TaskActivity.this);

                message.setText(task.getName());
                message.setId(task.getId());
                message.setLayoutParams(params);
                message.setTextSize(30);


                message.setBackground(getApplicationContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.task_text));

                Toast.makeText(TaskActivity.this, "Text loaded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                lm.addView(message);
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);

            }

        }
```

The `TextViews` appear at once no matter the timer. The app waits while the Timer for every circle of the loop and returns the hole `messengers` at once!

See the screenshot of the app:

[image]

So how would you do this task and resolve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: `SystemClock.sleep(1000);` will just freeze your app for a second. Never block main thread. You can try using a Handler to postpone some code

Comment: Also please edit the question title, as your title and tour question title do not match

Comment: i think that your solution for add to layout is not right. you should you ListView or RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the behaviour as in Messenger , you should use RecyclerView in android. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview
With the time interval to add a new message, you can use recyclerview notify methods to show the new messages.

Answer (score 0):

define a layout in which you need to add your textView and then do the following

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView tv=new TextView(this);

tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);

tv.setText("test");

this.parentLayout.addView(tv);
```

Comment: What did you change in your answer? Is the hole problem in getApplicationContext()?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running on the uiThread so the UI doesn't update until the loop is complete. Have a look at using an AsyncTask to pause the app in the background and do the update after finishing. Try something like this:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity
{

    Queue<String> messages = new LinkedList<String>();

    class PushNextMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected  void onPostExecute(Void _void)
        {
            String message = messages.remove();

            //this is where you add the view to the base layout

            if (messages.size() > 0)
            {
                new PushNextMessage().execute();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        messages.add("message 1");
        messages.add("message 2");
        messages.add("message 3");

        new PushNextMessage().execute();

    }


}
```